# How to port GTK2 pixmaps to GTK3_

Tags: gtk3, gtk2

I'm trying to port a Ruby application from GTK2 to GTK3 but I didn't find a way to draw GdkPixbufs to a window. With GTK2, I use the following dead simple code to draw 11 bitmaps to a GtkImage embedded in a parent window:

```
    def counter_setup
        @dpix = Gdk::Pixmap.new(@counter.window, 11*DIGIT_WIDTH, DIGIT_HEIGHT, -1)

        @digits = []
        10.times { |i| @digits[i] = GdkPixbuf::Pixbuf.new(file: Cfg.icons_dir+"#{i}digit.png", width: DIGIT_WIDTH, height: DIGIT_HEIGHT) }
        @digits[10] = GdkPixbuf::Pixbuf.new(file: Cfg.icons_dir+"unlitdigit.png", width: DIGIT_WIDTH, height: DIGIT_HEIGHT)
        @digits[11] = GdkPixbuf::Pixbuf.new(file: Cfg.icons_dir+"colondigit.png", width: DIGIT_WIDTH, height: DIGIT_HEIGHT)
        @digits[12] = GdkPixbuf::Pixbuf.new(file: Cfg.icons_dir+"minusdigit.png", width: DIGIT_WIDTH, height: DIGIT_HEIGHT)

        reset_counter
    end

    def reset_counter
        11.times do |i|
            if i == 2 || i == 8
                @dpix.draw_pixbuf(nil, @digits[11], 0, 0, i*DIGIT_WIDTH, 0, DIGIT_WIDTH, DIGIT_HEIGHT, Gdk::RGB::DITHER_NONE, 0, 0)
            elsif i == 5
                @dpix.draw_pixbuf(nil, @digits[12], 0, 0, i*DIGIT_WIDTH, 0, DIGIT_WIDTH, DIGIT_HEIGHT, Gdk::RGB::DITHER_NONE, 0, 0)
            else
                @dpix.draw_pixbuf(nil, @digits[10], 0, 0, i*DIGIT_WIDTH, 0, DIGIT_WIDTH, DIGIT_HEIGHT, Gdk::RGB::DITHER_NONE, 0, 0)
            end
        end
        @counter.set(@dpix, nil)
    end
```

The counter_setup method builds pixbuffs from files and creates a pixmap from the GtkImage (@counter.window). The reset_counter displays each pixbuf side by side in the window, and it looks like this:

[image]

On the image (taken from the GTK2 version), it's the top left widget, a time counter, redrawn every second, and that's the reason why it's not a single bitmap but a series of them.

From the GTK3 docs, pixmaps are gone and it's said Cairo should be used instead. The problem is that the only method I found to write bitmaps to a Cairo context is set_source_pixbuf but it doesn't do what I want...

Does anyone know how to achieve the same behavior using GTK3?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official GTK 2-to-3 migration guide on this topic: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch26s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.5

You didn't mention what you tried with `set_source_pixbuf` or why it didn't work, but did you try filling the surface with the pixbuf as in the example given there?

Alternatively, you might find it easier to use a series of GtkImage widgets placed next to each other, and set the pixbufs as their sources appropriately.